# VMWare ctrl-z key binding, how to remove

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vmware-server

When I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to my VM from my host the VM does not get keyboard input until I click inside it.  This is causing me an issue as it looks like the VM has control of the input (as the cursor is flashing away).  If while in this state, VMWare server has the focus rather then the application inside it, if you do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (normally for undo) it **suspends** the VM.

This is driving me barmey.  I have looked through all the options and preferences in VMWare Server and can't find anyway to disable this.

Anyone know how to disable this?

Comment: I have a similar problem with Ctrl-R: reboot in VMWare != Search back in bash.

Comment: S.Keller's solution worked for me and may fix your issue too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will not remove the key binding from VmWare, but you could set the option to "Grab keyboard and mouse intput on key press" in the VmWare preferences. VmWare help explicitly states that this will disable the system accelerator key sequences.

Comment: 3.5 years later and they haven't solved this issue (That I just started experiencing). Here's to hoping that the same solution works for the latest verions (as I wait for resume to complete grumble).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a resource editor on `vmware.exe` to remove the keybinding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.  Obviously not for the faint of heart.

Comment: That's a great solution. Resource Hacker did the trick for me. Edited accelerators for ID 40020 (in VMWare 7.1.5).